# 403 error when requesting Petfinder API Key

Tags: api-key, petfinder

I created a Petfinder account and tried getting an API key through https://www.petfinder.com/developers/signup/ but when I fill out my information, I get a 403 Forbidden error. Has anyone encountered this and resolved it?

I am trying to contact Petfinder support but they don't have clear contact information. I sent an email to help@petfinder.com but not even sure if that's the right email so I doubt they will email me back.